# Excel; How do I import CSV table as rows seperated by table number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, database, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

So I have a MASSIVE data set, in its unprocessed format it is a CSV file and contains two column tables that are stacked on top of one another. in the picture below the delimited version of the file is represented in columns A and B, with the first data set in A1:B3 the second in A5:B11 the third in A13:B19 and so on... there are over 7 million data points so doing this by hand would be an actual lifetime.

What i want the data to look like is the second picture, where i have created an equation which performs this action. however it cant account for discrepancies in table length; also VLOOKUP for the entire data set would crash my computer.

Somebody must know how i can import this data set and get the result i have described, please help!

**This is what the data set looks like prior to processing**

[image]

**This is what I want my data to end up like in F2:L9 Think of F2 as cell A1 in the final output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have quickly wrote some basic code for you to work off of for a macro to do this.

```
Sub RotateData()
    'Row 1
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 1
    'Column 1 or "A"
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 1

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Do While ws.Cells(r, c) <> ""
    Do While ws.Cells(r, c) <> ""
        ws.Cells(c, r + 5) = ws.Cells(r, c)
        r = r + 1
    Loop
        r = 1
        c = c + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

>

> This is the general idea as the `TRANSPOSE()` function in excel is limited to a set number of items to handle. I have handled 280mb csv files and have found that a separate workbook and just referencing the data set saves a lot of cpu and ram usage.
>
> This code does require you to have 'something' in each cell.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the r notation usage in excel, if I want to iterate through an entire sheet with this function what can I reference to do that?

Comment: The `r` notation is for your *row count* and the `c` notation is for the *column count*.  <br/>This is a macro so all you have to do is run this macro via the "developer" tab and it will move the columns of data. Just remember for the code above you must have no gaps in rows or columns or it will not transpose them all.<br/>This code is very basic an will still require some manual movement of cells, unfortunately.